# Correlation Matrix using pandas with empty values

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, correlation

Given the following data set:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

Data = {
    'a1': [,0,,0.01,0,0.03,0.01,0.01,,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,,,,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.02,0.03,0],
    'a2': [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,,0,,,],
    'a3': [,0,0.02,,,0,0.01,0.03,0,0.01,0.01,0.02,,,,,,,,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0.02,0,0,0.02,0,0,0,0.05],
    'a4': [,0,0,,0,0,,0,,,,,,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,,],
    'a5': [,0,0,0,0,,0,,,,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,],
    'a6': [,0.01,0,0,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0.01,0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.03,0.01,0.01,0.01,0,0.01,0,0.01,0],
    }
```

How can be created a correlation matrix using pandas and taking into account there are blank/empty values for some dimensions in the array? (those should be ignored)

I have tried reducing the minPeriods to 0.

```
df = DataFrame(Data,columns=['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'])

corrMatrix = df.corr(min_periods=0)
print (corrMatrix)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is actually the column type. Since you are using empty string to represent missing values, when pandas is creating dataframe, it is considering those columns as string columns (i.e. object), rather than numbers.

So before you calculate correlation, you need to convert the columns:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Then, you can do your correlation call:

```
df.corr(method='pearson')
```

Note that `min_perods=0` won't work with `pearson` correlation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Then, what can i do for those moments where there is no data available? Obviously, if I fill with zeros it works, but it deviates the correlation

Comment: @P00LR0CK If you look at the output from `df.corr()`, you notice there's no data for columns `a2, a4, a5`, that's because for those columns there's no variation in the data (either missing, which was dropped or all zeros). That's why the variance/correlation cannot be calculated for that column and for any column with that column.

Comment: I understand it, but how can be managed this kind of situation where there are missing values that should be ignored

Comment: @P00LR0CK `pd.corr()` does it automatically, so when it is calculating the correlation between two columns, it ignores all the rows which contain missing values.